# Docker: create a persistent volume in a specific directory

Tags: docker

I need to create a [persistent volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for Docker. The volume must be named `extra-addons` and  located in `/mnt/`.

I run this command:

```
sudo docker volume create /mnt/extra-addons
```

I got this error message:

```
Error response from daemon: create /mnt/extra-addons: "/mnt/extra-addons" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path
```

Note that when I simply run: `sudo docker volume create extra-addons`, I do not face this problem but when I inspect the volume in question using `sudo docker inspect extra-addons`, I see it is located in a place I do not want:

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2018-04-21T14:40:25+03:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/extra-addons/_data",
        "Name": "extra-addons",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

I mean I rather want to see the volume like this: `/mnt/extra-addons`

Any idea?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the solution:

I had to install [local-persist](https://github.com/CWSpear/local-persist) plugin.

I had to mount the volume to create to the mount point as follows:

```
 sudo docker volume create -d local-persist -o mountpoint=/mnt/ --name=extra-addons
```

Check if I got what I expected:

```
sudo docker volume inspect extra-addons
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "Driver": "local-persist",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/mnt/",
        "Name": "extra-addons",
        "Options": {
            "mountpoint": "/mnt/"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

That was what I am looking for.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want to install any plugins to your docker, I would recommend to create a symbolic link for your volume:

```
$ docker volume create <myVolume>
$ docker volume inspect <myVolume> 
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/<myVolume>/_data",
        "Name": "<myVolume>",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
$ mkdir /mnt/<myVolume>
# if you already have data in your volume, you should copy it to `/mnt/<myVolume>` now
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/volumes/<myVolume>/_data
$ sudo ln -s /mnt/<myVolume> /var/lib/docker/volumes/<myVolume>/_data
```

Now feel free to use your volume as usual (with all your data beeing in `/mnt` as you wanted)

Comment: Don't think it's a good idea deleting docker managed volumes. Use a mount instead to mount a host directory into docker.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think using the `local-persist` driver is the way to go. It hasn't been updated in a while. You can mount a local (host) directory into a docker container using docker mount.

Running the following creates a new container with a mounted directory mapped to my desktop.

```
mkdir extra-addons
docker run -it -v /Users/me/Desktop/extra-addons:/mnt/extra-addons busybox /bin/sh
ls
```

You can now see a `mnt` folder in root of your container.

`bin   dev   etc   home  mnt   proc  root  sys   tmp   usr   var`

Creating a new file in the container

`touch /mnt/extra-addons/test.txt`

Creates a test.txt file on my host machine. At the specified path. This is now a two way read/write shared folder. Multiple containers can mount the same folder. And it'll persist once you shut your container/s down.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this saved me a step. I was trying to add a volume. just mount the dir

Comment: this creates a bind mount, docker suggest to use volumes, and have several advantages
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: @JoeCabezas yeah volumes are a better choice for production given they're docker managed and isolated from other operating system tasks. But for this question _in a specific directory_ bind mounts are the answer. It does enhance the answer distinguishing the two.

Comment: thanks for the insight, you are right, in order to answer the question a bind volume is enough.

Comment: I specifically wanted to use a bind mount but was having issues with PostgreSQL until I found a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61884120/5362795). Just sharing because I ended up here when looking for a solution. Even though the question is for Windows, I had the same error on Linux.